# Beginner Redux/React - Add single item if not in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add a single item to my nested Redux state, if that item isn't already in the list.

I don't care about doing it in plain JS, I want the Redux sauce ofc.

My state looks like this:

```
  state: {
    data: {
      list: []
    },
  },
```

This is what I tried in my reducer:

```
  return {
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      list: [action.payload.list, ...state.data.list]
    }
  }
```

Problem is, sometimes the item I want to add is **already** in the array, therefore I have a duplicate in my list (which I don't want).

> How can I add an item to my list while checking first if this item is
>   already there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element won't be duplicated and always at 0 index,

```
return {
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      list: [].concat(action.payload.list, state.data.list.filter(val=>val.id==action.payload.list.id))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, much cleaner!

Comment: How we handle this without using concat()?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/some) method. It will return `true` or `false` and stop iterating over the array as soon as there is a match. Example:

```
case SOME_ACTION: {
  // iterate over the list and compare given item to item from action
  const existsInArray = state.data.list.some(l => l.id === action.payload.list.id)
  if(existsInArray) {
    return state;
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      list: [action.payload.list, ...state.data.list]
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

You wrote in a comment that if the element exists in the array you want to make that it will be the first item in the list. What I would do is filter out this element (if exists) and then put the item back from the action as the first element:

```
case SOME_ACTION: {
  // filter out the element
  const copyOfArray = state.data.list.filter(l => l.id !== action.payload.list.id)
  // put to the beginning of the array
  copyOfArray.unshift(action.payload.list);

  return {
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      list: copyOfArray
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `l is not defined`

Comment: @mokiliiiLo sorry, updated. But the thing is you need to invent your own way to compare objects. That's just an example.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way to place this element in the very first position in my list?

Comment: Yes, but in the case of the item being already in the list, its position isn't changed. Is there a way to enforce the fact that the position, in the end, will always be 0?